# strip away html tags from extracted links

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to extract certain links from a webpage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib2, sys 
import re 

def tonaton(): 
    site = "http://tonaton.com/en/job-vacancies-in-ghana" 
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr) 
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    invalid_tag = ('h2') 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass) 
    print soup.find_all('h2')
```

The links are contained in the 'h2' tags so I get the links as follows:

```
<h2><a href="/en/cashiers-accra">cashiers </a></h2> 
<h2><a href="/en/cake-baker-accra">Cake baker</a></h2> 
<h2><a href="/en/automobile-technician-accra">Automobile Technician</a></h2> 
<h2><a href="/en/marketing-officer-accra-4">Marketing Officer</a></h2>
```

But I'm interested in getting rid of all the 'h2' tags so that I have links only in this manner:

```
<a href="/en/cashiers-accra">cashiers </a> 
<a href="/en/cake-baker-accra">Cake baker</a> 
<a href="/en/automobile-technician-accra">Automobile Technician</a> 
<a href="/en/marketing-officer-accra-4">Marketing Officer</a>
```

I therefore updated my code to look like this:

```
def tonaton(): 
    site = "http://tonaton.com/en/job-vacancies-in-ghana" 
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr) 
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    invalid_tag = ('h2') 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass) 
    jobs = soup.find_all('h2') 
    for tag in invalid_tag: 
        for match in jobs(tag): 
            match.replaceWithChildren() 
    print jobs
```

But I couldn't get it to work, even though  I thought that was the best logic i could come up with.I'm a newbie though so I know there is something better that could be done.

Any help will be gracefully appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could navigate for the next element of each `<h2>` tag:

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    n = h2.next_element
    if n.name == 'a':  print n
```

It yields:

```
<a href="/en/financial-administrator-accra-1">Financial Administrator</a>
<a href="/en/house-help-accra-17">House help</a>
<a href="/en/office-manager-accra-1">Office Manager </a>
...
```